# Mergefield in Word table with tabs and return characters

Tags: ms-word, mergefield

I have a Word Document that is made up of tables, rows, columns, cells. It pulls data using Mergefield, during generation of the document. I want a row of references, with the ability to reduce line returns by having tabs between the reference name and value, but also not put in a line character within any reference name and value based on word wrap.

Example of references:

[image]

However I am looking for it to be clean where there would be a line return before the new 'Pickup Number:', with value Austin, reference and not just because of the space.

Comment: This is not a programming question and, as such, is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Questions on general usage of Microsoft Word should be asked on an appropriate end-use forum (e.g., MS Answers).

Comment: @macropod is it possible to move to that forum?

Comment: @macropod ya not seeing that at https://stackexchange.com/sites